# SQL Insert New Column Based on Other Columns and Previous Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server, I am trying to add a fourth column to the table below, based on the qualifier and value columns. If the qualifier is 130, then the new column should be whatever number is in the value column. If the qualifier isn't 130, it should use the previous value associated with the most recent qualifier 130 row.

```
PrimaryKey | Qualifier | Value
001        | 130       | 3
002        | 207       | 24
003        | 301       | 27
004        | 130       | 8
005        | 810       | 1
002        | 900       | 9
```

The above table would become the below table.

```
PrimaryKey | Qualifier | Value | NewColumn
001        | 130       | 3     | 3
002        | 207       | 24    | 3
003        | 301       | 27    | 3
004        | 130       | 8     | 8
005        | 810       | 1     | 8
002        | 900       | 9     | 8
```

I was trying to do this with lag, but couldn't figure out how to self reference the NewColumn. I also then experimented with setting a variable, but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use sum + first_value like this:

```
select *, first_value(Value) over (partition by GRP order by PrimaryKey) from (
  select *, sum(case when Qualifier = '130' then 1 else 0 end) 
            over (order by PrimaryKey) as GRP
  from #tmp
) X
```

The sum + case in the inner select creates separate number for each grouping that starts with qualifier 130, and then first value uses that to partition the result.

[Example](http://rextester.com/CJD52620)

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest method is `outer apply`:

```
select t.*, t2.value as newcolumn
from t outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.qualifier = 130 and t2.primarykey <= t.primarykey
      order by t2.primarykey desc
     ) t2;
```

Comment: i played around with this, but my actual table now requires a join and i couldn't get this solution to work (which means i'm doing something wrong given i'm new to all of this). appreciate the response, and I'm going to keep playing with this. for now, i got the other solution to work.